# Prove existence of expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a nonmonotone convex function. Prove that existence of $\mathbb{E}g(X)$ implies existence of $\mathbb{E}X$.
I know that exists distributions with undefined expectation, but I can't really understand how I suppose to prove existence of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pictorially, if you have a convex function and you choose any point on it and draw a tangent line (or subgradient), then the convex function is always above or on the tangent line. So $aX + b \le g(X)$ everywhere. This gives you either an upper or lower bound on $X$ relative to $a^{-1}(g(X) - b)$ which depends on the sign of $a$.

Next, $g$ is not monotone so we get subgradient lines with positive and negative slopes. That gives you both an upper and a lower bound on $X$. So the expectation exists.